# DokuWiki nested lists regexp

Tags: ruby, regex, markup, dokuwiki

How can i replace DokuWiki nested list string with using one or two regexps in Ruby?

For example, if we have this string:

```
  * one
  * two
    * three
  * four
```

we should get this HTML:

- one
- two

  - three
- four

I've made a regexp replacing the whole list. E.g.:

```
s.sub!(/(^\s+\*\s.+$)+/m, '<ul>\1</ul>')
```

And it works as it should. But how to replace the single list items?

Comment: Which version of Ruby do you use ?

Comment: @Stephan 1.9.3p194 as for now

Comment: Did you solve this problem or do you still need any help ?

Comment: @Stephan if i'd solve the problem, this question was closed ;) So, yeah, i need help with this =)

Answer (score 1):

**The regex :**

Here are some example lists :

```
  * first item
  * second item

No longer a list

  * third item? no, it's the first item of the second list

  * first item 
  * second item with linebreak\\ second line
  * third item with code: <code>
some code
comes here
</code>
  * fourth item
```

The regex for matching all lists

```
(?<=^|\n)(?: {2,}\*([^\n]*?<code>.*?</code>[^\n]*|[^\n]*)\n?)+
```

View it in action : http://rubular.com/r/VMjwbyhJTm

**The code :**

Surround all lists with a `<ul>...</ul>`

```
s.sub!(/(?<=^|\n)(?: {2,}\*(?:[^\n]*?<code>.*?<\/code>[^\n]*|[^\n]*)\n?)+/m, '<ul>\0</ul>')
```

Add missing `<li>`s (**s2** in the following code is the string with `<ul>...</ul>` added)

```
s2.sub!(/ {2,}\*([^\n]*?<code>.*?<\/code>[^\n]*|[^\n]*)\n?/m, '<li>\1</li>')
```

**Note :**
Nested lists can not be handled with this regex. If this is a requirement, a parser will be more adapted !

Comment: That's the reason why i stopped thinking regexp on this problem ;)